# s3 bucket object URL is not private

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My buckets folders are private, but when I copy the URL of an individual object into a browser (when I'm logged out), I can still download/view the file.

How can I prevent this?

Here's my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "NotResource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/backup/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I am trying to achieve: make every folder private except for 2 folders called `media` and `static` (which I want public read access for).

Comment: If you _remove_ the bucket policy, are the individual objects still accessible? What are you hoping to achieve from this policy -- I've never seen a bucket policy with a `NotResource`?

Comment: I'm trying to make every folder private except for two folders called `media` and `static`

Comment: If you _remove_ the bucket policy, are the individual objects still accessible? And when you say that an object is still accessible, which folder is it in?

Comment: From reading the answers and comments on this page, it would appear that there is confusion about your actual objectives. Feel free to edit your question to state what you are actually trying to achieve rather than just saying "this doesn't work".

Comment: My mistake, I've added my objective in my edit. When I remove the bucket policy, all my folders are private and can't be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

In your policy your are specifically telling it allow anonymous public GET Access.

You have to change it to something like below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:user/USERNAME_A",
                    "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:user/USERNAME_B",
                    "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:user/USERNAME_C",
                    "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/ROLE_A",
                    "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/ROLE_B",
                    "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/ROLE_C"
                ]
            },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Refer more policy [examples](https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/6215d9e80021c1f8de12) here.

Comment: I also would like to make two folders called `media` and `static` public -  does this change the configuration you've posted?

Comment: OK, yes you could do it. refer `Restricted LIST & PUT/DELETE access to specific path within a bucket` section of the URL I have provide and change `LIST/PUT/DELETE` to `GetObject`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
    {
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
       "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInOtherFolders",
       "Action":["s3:*"],
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"],
       "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":
                  [
                       "backup/media/*"
                       "backup/static/*"
                  ]
               }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Please refer this [Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/) for more details.

Comment: It is not advisable to grant `s3:*` permissions. This means that anyone in the world can do anything without those allowed paths (including listing files, deleting them and uploading TBs of data, for which you will be charged).

Answer (score 0):

This policy grants public `GetObject` access to the two folders.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ReadAccess",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::jr-enc/media/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::jr-enc/static/*"
            ],
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that `GetObject` only grants access to access/download an object. It does *not* give permission to list the contents of the bucket/folders.